# WF 4.0: FaultException<TDetail> thrown from WCF service gets converted to FaultException

Tags: workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

The fault exception (i.e.FaultException) thrown from the WCF service in the WF 4.0 is getting converted to the generic FaultException (System.ServiceModel.FaultException). But, when I consume the same WCF service in a Console application or asp.net application will get the correct fault exception (i.e. (FaultException))  thrown.

In the workflow(4.0) i need to catch the same Non-generic fault exception (FaultException) thrown from the WCF.

Does anybody know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your post is a little old, but I came across this same problem.  I followed the link of the previous answer, but our solution came from [this post on msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar-SA/wfprerelease/thread/79ea8653-65f5-4637-bbed-521b605683c3)

It has to do with adding the type to the xaml generated from the service reference.  The problem is of course this involves manually editing generated code, so if the service reference gets updated the changes will be wiped out. If I find a solution to that problem I'll update this post.